# mvn jar file : library include failed

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I did `mvn package` and  ran my file by doing `java -jar target\output.jar`

All the jar libraries specified in the dependency of pom.xml are not included. Do advice what's wrong below. Thanks!

Below is my pom.xml to allow jar file generation.

```
    <plugin>
        <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.workspez.psg.letrikEtara.PlanetGroupLetrikEtara</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and compare/complete your declaration with the ones in "[Including dependencies in a jar with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55914163/6309)", like adding the `executions` section.

Or, if this is not working, consider the [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/), whic can achieve a simlar goal.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working.  This was missing:

`<descriptorRefs>
     <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
</descriptorRefs>`

To the following should work:

```
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.workspez.psg.letrikEtara.PlanetGroupLetrikEtara</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```